# Disable some value on JSF Dropdown list

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a dropdown list that's generated from a map object, that would be repeated depending of the number of list I get from DB, for example, 5 items from the DB, it would generate 5 dropdown list for each row.

I can get the value of the dropdownlist by assign it to a variable in the list, but what I wanted is, to disable certain selected value from the list.

For example, if I have in the dropdownlist the following items (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and if for the first row I select the item 1, then the following dropdownlists would only have the remaining items available/selectable (2,3,4,5).

I know I can use `<p:ajax>`, but is there any idea how to disable the item?

```
<p:dataTable var="tableDefinition" id="tableDefinition" value="#{fileUploadManagedBean.theTableList}" rowIndexVar="tdi">
    <p:column headerText="no" width="2%">
        <h:outputText value="#{tdi + 1}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Header" width="25%">
        <h:outputText value="#{tableDefinition.header}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Sample Value" width="25%">
        <h:outputText value="#{tableDefinition.sampleValue}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Map Field" width="25%">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="fieldList" 
                         value="#{tableDefinition.fieldName}" style="width:150px" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['form.import.upload_type_select']}" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{fileUploadManagedBean.fieldTypes}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Btw just to share with others, here is what I put on my backing bean :

```
 public void doCheckList(String fieldType){
 Set<String> keySet = selectedFieldTypes.keySet();

    Iterator<String> iterator = keySet.iterator();

    List<String> removeList = new ArrayList();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String selectedField = iterator.next();
        boolean isEqual = false;
        for(int i=0;i<theTableList.size();i++){
            TableDefinition tdef = theTableList.get(i);
            String fieldName = tdef.getFieldName();

            if(selectedField.equals(fieldName)){
                isEqual = true;
            }

            if(i == (selectedFieldTypes.size() - 1) && !isEqual){
                removeList.add(selectedField);
            }

    }
    }

    if(removeList.size()>0){
        for(String fieldToRemove:removeList){
            if(fieldToRemove!=null){
                selectedFieldTypes.remove(fieldToRemove);
            }
        }
    }
    selectedFieldTypes.put(fieldType,fieldType);
 }
public boolean isItemSelected(String fieldType) {       
    return selectedFieldTypes.containsKey(fieldType);
}
```

And here's what I change for my select one menu :

```
         <p:selectOneMenu  id="fieldList" value="#{tableDefinition.fieldName}" style="width:150px" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['form.import.upload_type_select']}" itemValue=" " itemDisabled="#{fileUploadManagedBean.isItemSelected(item)}" />

            <f:selectItems value="#{fileUploadManagedBean.fieldTypes}" var="item" itemDisabled="#{fileUploadManagedBean.isItemSelected(item)}" />
            <p:ajax onstart="showAjaxLoading();" oncomplete="hideAjaxLoading();" listener="#{fileUploadManagedBean.doCheckList(tableDefinition.fieldName)}" update=":importData" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem I'm having now is that the disabled item is detect as null in the backing bean (the value is not passed) even though it's already selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `itemDisabled` property:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['form.import.upload_type_select']}" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
<f:selectItems value="#{fileUploadManagedBean.fieldTypes}" var="item" itemDisabled="#{fileUploadManagedBean.isItemSelected(item)}"/>
```

And in your backing bean:

```
public boolean isItemSelected(FieldType fieldType) {
     return selectedFieldTypes.contains(fieldType)
}
```

Comment: Good answer, wonder why this,is so difficult for others to find out

Comment: @Kukeltje: Lack of basic HTML knowledge. One with basic HTML knowledge would already know that you'd use `<option disabled>` attribute for this and then check in JSF `<f:selectItem(s)>` tag documentation how to let it generate such HTML output and then have discovered `itemDisabled` attribute.

Comment: @BalusC Yep but with taglib files, you have codecompletion in your IDE… and what about some simple usage of a search engine. Dozens of hits…  so it is not only lack of basic html knowledge, but also lack of investigation and other basic development knowledge

Comment: Thank you bro, this work like a charm, I change the method to my map name (the fieldTypes object), and use the containKey() method to disable on at a time :).